# dirpaginate results in same number of rows for different scope variables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 3 list items and for each I have a div:-

`<div class="tabs">
    <h3>Legislaotrs</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#ByState" onclick="showDiv('ByState','ByHouse','BySenate')">By State</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ByHouse" onclick="showDiv('ByHouse','ByState','BySenate')">House</a></li>
        <li><a href="#BySenate" onclick="showDiv('BySenate','ByState','ByHouse')">Senate</a></li></ul>
</div>`

The div's are as follows:-

`<div id="ByState">
    <div class="search" style="float: right;">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Search</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
         </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Party</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Chamber</th> <th>District</th> <th>State</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:['state_name','fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10"> 
            <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
            <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
            <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
            <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div>`

The second div:-

`<div id="ByHouse" style="display: none;">
    <div class="search" style="float: right;">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Search</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
         </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Party</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Chamber</th> <th>District</th> <th>State</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr dir-paginate="user in house|orderBy:['fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10"> 
            <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
            <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
            <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
            <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div>`

The 3rd div:-

`<div id="BySenate" style="display: none">
    <div class="search" style="float: right;">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Search</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
         </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Party</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Chamber</th> <th>District</th> <th>State</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr dir-paginate="user in senate|orderBy:['fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10"> 
            <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
            <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
            <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
            <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div>`

The problem is that the dirpaginate that repeats over the $scope variables produces the same number of results. The $scope.users has 538 rows, the $scope.house has 438 rows while the $scope.senate has 100 rows. But each of the divs above produces only 100 rows. Can someone please help me where I am going wrong. If I comment out the last 2 divs then the first div gives the correct number of rows. So basically the combination of all 3 doesnot work but individually they work fine. Can some one please help now??

Answer (score 0):

All the  were going for the default pagination-id because I had not given any pagination-id. Created pagination-id for each div and then placed the  under each table with the respective pagination-id attribute. This solved the issue.

The changes in my code:-

`<tr dir-paginate="senate in senate|orderBy:['fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="bySenate">`

and

`<div id="controls" class="controls" align="center">
    <dir-pagination-controls
        pagination-id="bySenate"
        max-size="5"
        direction-links="true"
        boundary-links="true" >
    </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>`

Made the above changes for all the three div's in question.